# How to custom UI Slider with Unity UGUI

Tags: unity, ui-design

I want to use Unity UGUI to custom a slider and the final looking show be like this:

[image]

And the images I use are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I found it hard to accomplish:

The handle will be screeched and the fill will not be fully filled with the handle

[image]

Can somebody tell me how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just using the normal slider that unity provides you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are stretching the handle by setting these values. For the fill issue I would have to see a image to tell why it is not filling properly. 
[image]

set those to 0,0 that way they will also scale properly with bigger screens. then select the rect transform and in the anchor preset use Ctrl Alt Click Left. and keep the other on stretch. You can also adjust the pivot X to something around -1 to bring the handle over to better match with the fill but the fill itself may still need adjustment if that doesn't solve the filling issue.

Comment: set those to 0,0 that way they will also scale properly with bigger screens. then select the rect transform and in the anchor preset use Ctrl Alt Click Left. and keep the other on stretch. You can also adjust the pivot X to something around -1 to bring the handle over to better match with the fill but the fill itself may still need adjustment if that doesn't solve the filling issue.

Comment: I think you should edit that comment in to the end of the answer instead.